# ajax best way to secure authentification

Tags: ajax, security, authentication, encryption, header

Using Ajax, to access one of my service I need to provide an user name and a password through a header.

To do so I'm using the beforesend function as follow:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('my_username:my_password'));
}
```

My problem is that everybody can see the value of the variables my_username and my_password

What is the best way to hide those variables from my users?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to know who the user is? The solution above does not help with that. Do you want to make sure only your javascript can connect and not others? That is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a proxy file - for example a PHP - where you can create the header and then send it to you server.

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'MakeRequest.php,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {your_data},
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(data) {
                      /*Success*/

                     },error: function(data) {
                      /*Error*/
                    }
                });
```

Then on your PHP (or whatever your are using) file you can use CURL to make the request to the server with your authentication.

Comment: And what will keep an attacker from accessing the service through the php file? :)

Comment: Server side no one can see the token that is being used making the requests - he will need to save that on the database, cookie or localstorage

Comment: Yes, but there is the client, which needs to connect to this php, which will then do the query to the actual service. As an attacker, why can't I use this php instead of the original service? It will just add the correct credentials for me.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark That does not even touch on the correct answer. HTTPS does not address the problem, nor does this answer help. The problem is that it's unclear what the asker wants to achieve.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I missed the part where he said "from my users".